# webbrowser control c# find occurance of the following text

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

i would like to do a test to see if the following text shows up on my webbroswer control

```
<form method="post" action=""><table border="0" class="formPage"><tr><td colspan="2" class="msg">Link submitted and awaiting approval.<br />Submit another link.</td></tr>
```

Im looking for the text "Link submitted and awaiting approval."

Comment: Could you rephrase the question ? 
Are you asking if the HTML is valid ? Or how does one display this HTML in a Web browser control ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use something like this:

```
if(webBrowser.DocumentText.Contains("Link submitted and awaiting approval.")) {
    // Do something.
}
```